# A IMO problem about geometry which can probably be solved by simple angle chasing.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> A circle has centre on the side $AB$ of a cyclic quadrilateral $ABCD$ . The other three sides are tangent to the circle. Prove that $AD+BC=AB$.

**My Attempt:**
I extended $DA$ and $BC$ to meet at X.Clearly, The circle is the incircle of $\Delta XCD$ and the line $AB$ is antiparallel to base $CD$. Now Cut $AT$ from $ AB$ where $AT=AD$.Enough to show $BT=BC$.I failed to do anything after this.I believe by finding some cyclic quadrilaterals and by angle chasing it can be done. Please help me.

Comment: @abiessu If $DA$ and $BC$ are parallel, the quadrilateral is a rectangle and this special case is easy to solve.

Comment: @abiessu & B.Mehta I assume that $DA & BC$ are not parallel by excluding the special case.

Comment: $X$ cannot be on the side that puts the circle inside $XCD$.

Comment: @B.Mehta You could also get a right trapezoid. Not sure if there are more cases to consider, but it is still annoying to make a (formal enough) proof that encompasses every cases in an unequivocal fashion.
@ OP A priori, the circle does not intersect with segments $XC$ and $XD$, and isn't tangent to these segments? Unless you say a segment is tangent to the circle if the infinite line is. Regardless, there are cases where the circle is not the incircle.

Comment: All the cases are easy. The main problem is solving this post!

Comment: My thoughts on an approach: since $AB$ goes through the center and must intersect the circle twice, making radii from the center to the tangent points of $BC$ and $AD$ should be informative (for non-parallel $BC, AD$).

Comment: @abiessu I thought about that before! Please help me how it is helpful

Comment: Both of the answers given use these radii.

Answer (score 2):

If $\angle OAD=\alpha$, then $\angle FOC=\alpha/2$ and:
$$
AO-AE=r(\csc\alpha-\cot\alpha)=r{1-\cos\alpha\over\sin\alpha}=
r\tan{\alpha\over2}=FC,
$$
where $r=OE=OF$ is the radius of the inscribed circle. In the same way one derives $BO-BF=ED$ and adding these two equalities we get the desired result.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The angle chase ---which relies upon the fact that opposite angles of an inscribed quadrilateral are supplementary--- gives us this figure:

[image]

The result then follows from the identity illustrated in this trigonograph:

[image]

> $$\tan\theta + \cot 2\theta = \csc 2\theta$$